# Android Studio project for Redbearlab BLE Shield apps

Tags: shields, bluetooth

To interact with its [BLE shield](http://redbearlab.com/bleshield/), Redbearlab published sample Android apps in the Play Store. The sources for the apps are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/RedBearLab/Android). How can I build them in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than expected to put together the Android Studio projects. They are on [GitHub now](https://github.com/ryklith/RBL_for_Android_Studio).

Note that the apps built from source are actually different from the ones published by Redbearlabs on the Play Store. On top of that, the chat app is not working.